# Capture the contents of a sequence of matching parenthesis with a regex expression

Tags: regex

I have the following text:

```
y=asin(pi*2*(vel_rot+(dan_int+didt)/2.));
```

I want a regex expression capturing the parameters to the function asin, i.e, in the example, it should match:

```
pi*2*(vel_rot+(dan_int+didt)/2.)
```

My issue is that I dont know how to skip as many closing parenthesis as opening parenthesis I find

Comment: If you are using perl, how about **y=asin[(](.*)[)]**    ? You can capture the contents of parenthesis. Does this occur in a single line? If it occurs in some surrounding context, the parenthesis may not match correctly.

Comment: Balancing parentheses is the canonical example of a problem that cannot be solved with a pure regular expression.   Some languages support extended regular expressions which allow this sort of thing, but is there some reason this has to be done with a regex?   A very simple loop and counter would be a straightforward and efficient solution for what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @JimLewis I agree. There are some editors though that offer find/substitute tools that only accept regex. Using a regex would save me the time to implement something else

Comment: @Andres Good point...sometimes a regex is all you have to work with, so it's good to know how to do it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a PCRE(or Perl) style engine that supports recursion.
Or, you can use Dot-Nets counting group to navigate nesting.

This is the former.

`y=asin(\(((?:[^()]++|(?1))*)\))`

Explained

```
 y=asin
 (                       # (1 start), Recursion code group
      \(
      (                       # (2 start), Capture, inner core
           (?:                     # Cluster group
                [^()]++                 # Possesive, not parenth's
             |                        # or,
                (?1)                    # Recurse to group 1
           )*                      # End cluster, do 0 to many times
      )                       # (2 end)
      \)
 )                       # (1 end)
```

Output

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 40 ) 
y=asin(pi*2*(vel_rot+(dan_int+didt)/2.))  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 6 , len 34 ) 
(pi*2*(vel_rot+(dan_int+didt)/2.))  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 7 , len 32 ) 
pi*2*(vel_rot+(dan_int+didt)/2.)
```